# MySQL syntax error when using question mark placeholders in prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Tried everything I can think of and I've narrowed down to the "?" placeholders.

I've tried replacing the "?" placeholders with random text and all works well (except of course it keeps overwriting the same row).

The error I get:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 
>               ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
>                   produ' at line 2

Here is my code (I would provide more but it all works well except for this bug, and if I remove the "?" placeholders then all works perfectly except that the values are not dynamic, but please ask if you suspect the issue is elsewhere):

```
    // Create MySQL connection to ds_signifyd_api
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect( $db_server_name, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name );
    // Check connection
    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
        exit( $mysqliFailedBody );
    }

    $mainProdQueryStmt = "INSERT INTO products (`product_id`, `title`, `body_html`, `vendor`, `product_type`, `created_at`, `handle`, `updated_at`, `published_at`, `template_suffix`, `published_scope`, `tags`) 
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
            product_id = VALUES(product_id), 
            title = VALUES(title), 
            body_html = VALUES(body_html),
            vendor = VALUES(vendor), 
            product_type = VALUES(product_type), 
            created_at = VALUES(created_at), 
            handle = VALUES(handle), 
            updated_at = VALUES(updated_at), 
            published_at = VALUES(published_at), 
            template_suffix = VALUES(template_suffix), 
            published_scope = VALUES(published_scope), 
            tags = VALUES(tags)";

        $product_id = $product_title = $body_html = $vendor = $product_type = $created_at = $handle = $updated_at = $published_at = $template_suffix = $published_scope = $tags = "";

        foreach ($dss_product_db_array as $product) {

            $product_id = $product['id'];
            //... more variables here...
            $tags = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $tags);              

            if (!mysqli_query($mysqli, $mainProdQueryStmt)) {
                printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($mysqli));
            }

            $mainProdQuery->bind_param("isssssssssss", $product_id, $product_title, $body_html, $vendor, $product_type, $created_at, 
                $handle, $updated_at, $published_at, $template_suffix, $published_scope, $tags);
            $mainProdQuery->execute();
    //      $mainProdQuery->close();
       }
```

### UPDATE

Implemented the fixes mentioned here:
1.  Stopped using `mysqli_real_escape_string`
2.  Binding variables outside loop
3.  Using only the object oriented method, as opposed to mixing them as in the case of `mysqli_query($mysqli, $mainProdQueryStmt)` VS `$mysqli->prepare($mainProdQueryStmt)` as it should have been -- this solved the "?" placeholders syntax error being incorrectly reported

Now everything works perfectly, no errors.

Updated Code:

```
    $mainProdQueryStmt = "INSERT INTO dss_products (`product_id`, `title`, `body_html`, `vendor`, `product_type`, `created_at`, `handle`, `updated_at`, `published_at`, `template_suffix`, `published_scope`, `tags`) 
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
            product_id = VALUES(product_id), 
            title = VALUES(title), 
            body_html = VALUES(body_html),
            vendor = VALUES(vendor), 
            product_type = VALUES(product_type), 
            created_at = VALUES(created_at), 
            handle = VALUES(handle), 
            updated_at = VALUES(updated_at), 
            published_at = VALUES(published_at), 
            template_suffix = VALUES(template_suffix), 
            published_scope = VALUES(published_scope), 
            tags = VALUES(tags)";

    $mainProdQuery = $mysqli->prepare($mainProdQueryStmt);
    if ($mainProdQuery === FALSE) {
        die($mysqli->error);
    }

    $product_id = $product_title = $body_html = $vendor = $product_type = $created_at = $handle = $updated_at = $published_at = $template_suffix = $published_scope = $tags = "";
    $mainProdQuery->bind_param("isssssssssss", $product_id, $product_title, $body_html, $vendor, $product_type, $created_at, 
        $handle, $updated_at, $published_at, $template_suffix, $published_scope, $tags);

    if ($mainProdQuery) {

        foreach ($dss_product_db_array as $product) {

            $product_id = $product['id'];
            $product_title = $product['title'];
            $body_html = $product['body_html'];
            $vendor = $product['vendor'];
            $product_type = $product['product_type'];
            $created_at = $product['created_at'];
            $handle = $product['handle'];
            $updated_at = $product['updated_at'];   
            $published_at = $product['published_at'];
            $template_suffix = $product['template_suffix'];
            $published_scope = $product['published_scope'];
            $tags = $product['tags'];

            if (!$mysqli->prepare($mainProdQueryStmt)) {
                printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
            }
            $mainProdQuery->execute();
        }
    }
```

Comment: your code doesn't make sense. You're using a prepared statement yet later on, you're using `mysqli_real_escape_string()` and there are a few unknown variables. Ok, you've answers below, deal with those. I'll show my way out now.

Comment: In order to use placeholders, you need to use [`->prepare()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) not `mysqli_query()`.  `$mysqli->prepare($mainProdQueryStmt)` not `mysqli_query($mysqli, $mainProdQueryStmt)`

Comment: If it overwrites the same row, then you need to look at your `KEY`

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use placeholders you have to use `mysqli_prepare()`, you can't use `mysqli_query()`. It looks like you intended to do that, but somehow that code got lost, since you use a variable `$mainProdQuery` that you never assigned.

You should prepare the query and bind the parameters just once, outside the loop. Then call `execute()` inside the loop.

```
$mainProdQueryStmt = "INSERT INTO products (`product_id`, `title`, `body_html`, `vendor`, `product_type`, `created_at`, `handle`, `updated_at`, `published_at`, `template_suffix`, `published_scope`, `tags`) 
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
        product_id = VALUES(product_id), 
        title = VALUES(title), 
        body_html = VALUES(body_html),
        vendor = VALUES(vendor), 
        product_type = VALUES(product_type), 
        created_at = VALUES(created_at), 
        handle = VALUES(handle), 
        updated_at = VALUES(updated_at), 
        published_at = VALUES(published_at), 
        template_suffix = VALUES(template_suffix), 
        published_scope = VALUES(published_scope), 
        tags = VALUES(tags)";
$mainProdQuery = $mysqli->prepare($mainProdQueryStmt);
$mainProdQuery->bind_param("isssssssssss", $product_id, $product_title, $body_html, $vendor, $product_type, $created_at, 
            $handle, $updated_at, $published_at, $template_suffix, $published_scope, $tags);
foreach ($dss_product_db_array as $product) {

    $product_id = $product['id'];
    //... more variables here...
    $mainProdQuery->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're running the query before it's properly prepared, and then, after the fact, attempting to bind to something that's not the right type, it's not a statement handle but a result set. You need to structure it this way:

```
$mainProdQueryStmt = "INSERT INTO products (`product_id`, `title`, `body_html`, `vendor`, `product_type`, `created_at`, `handle`, `updated_at`, `published_at`, `template_suffix`, `published_scope`, `tags`) 
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
        product_id = VALUES(product_id), 
        ...
        tags = VALUES(tags)";

// Prepare the statement to get a statement handle
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($mainProdQueryStmt);

foreach ($dss_product_db_array as $product) {
    // Bind to this statement handle the raw values (non-escaped)
    $stmt->bind_param("isssssssssss",
        $product['id'], $product['title'], ...);

    // Execute the query
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Try to avoid creating heaps of throw-away variables an just bind *directly* to the values in question, like those in `$product`. The variables do nothing useful and only introduce opportunities for silly mistakes.

Comment: What do you mean by result set?

Comment: There's no need to keep preparing the same statement.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, you can prepare once. I just tried to fix the minumum amount possible to make this thing operational. I'll update that.

Comment: @barmar I mean a [result set](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) object which is what you get back from a `query()` call. It looks like `$mainProdQuery` is never properly assigned in the original, but presumably it was intended to be the result of that query.

Comment: I think it was intended to be the result of prepare, but he never finished converting the code to to a prepared statement.

Comment: Upvoted for suggestion regarding useless variables, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Try using PDO(PhP Data Objects) prepared statements. It's less painful to work with and cross database i.e can be used with any RDBMS. See PDO [Official Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [here](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo)

Comment: this is a comment and a suggestion. It does not solve the question.